# Open Missing in Right Click Menu for Large Set of HTML file in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu

I  have number of locally stored HTML files that I want to open in Google Chrome (or any default web browser). When I right click on number of HTML files, after selecting about 15 of them, the OPEN menu item disappears from right click menu.

How can I select all the files and open them by right clicking and clicking **Open**?

Below screenshots describes the issue.

**Selecting 15 files and Right clicking**

[image: selecting multiple files in windows explorer]

**Selecting 16 or more files and Right clicking**

[image: No open option for right click menu]

I am not sure why **Open** menu item disappears. Please help.

Comment: This has got to do with the shell extension evaluating the files before the menu item creation.  Why?  Who knows.  Workaround?  Drag onto chrome OR put chrome into your  SendTo folder.

Comment: If I drag all these files into Chrome, Google Chrome only opens one of them! I added the google chrome exe shortcut in the SendTo folder. And then if I select all files and "Send To" Chrome, it works. So, thank you. But it still is a workaround. Not sure why explorer would be ok with opening 15 files, but not more!! Thank you.

Comment: Probably to prevent the explorer from getting hung with a bajillion files on the right click.  If you want the REAL reason, under the hood, there is a handler interface called `IShellFolder::EnumObjects` that gets called when you right click.  The entire explorer is hung while this function processes the items in the list.  For some reason, they bail out after the 15th item.  Testers like to break things.. so one probably tried to right click 50 bajillion items and hung the shell.  This was probably a solution but WHY 15?? We will never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft set 15 as the maximum number of files that you can open at the same time to prevent some computers from crashing. but here is how you can fix it.

start ---> Run ---> regedit

Navigate to:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
```

create a `DWORD` (32-BIT) and call it `MultipleInvokePromptMinimum`

choose decimal and enter the maximum number of files that you would like to open at the same time.

This is how it looks:

[image]

and this is the proof in my own registry. as you can see I have 20 files selected and I can right click and choose open.

[image]

Here is a link found by @Moab confirming the mentioned above.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/context-menus-shortened-select-over-15-files

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: the reference is my own pc and my registry, i added 2 screenshots to make it clearer, if you want me to add another pic with the value you choose, please tell me.

Comment: No that.s fine.

Comment: alright! please tell me if my answer helped you, or if you require more assistance.

Comment: It's not my question :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/context-menus-shortened-select-over-15-files

Comment: Moab, thanks a lot. @Michel, please add the link that Moab has put in your answer as a reference and I will select it as a answer. Thanks.